# Breeze + Entity Framework 5 + Stored Procedures in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, breeze

I am using Breeze.js as a dataservice in my SPA application, but I want to use stored procedures for deleting some of my entities in the SQL database.

I managed to get the client call the stored procedure in the database but I still have some issues.

The method that calls the stored procedure in the Breeze controller looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
    [ActionName("deletecustomer")]
    public object DeleteCustomer([FromUri] string customerName)
    {
        string query = "sp_delete_customer @CustomerName";
        SqlParameter CustomerName = new SqlParameter("@CustomerName", customerName);
        var result = _dataContext.Context.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>(query, CustomerName);
        return result;
    }
```

I am calling it from the breeze manager:

```
 var deleteCustomer = function (customerName) {
        var query = EntityQuery.from('DeleteCustomer')
               .withParameters({ customerName: customerName });

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);
}
```

The problem is that I still receive a `Internal Server Error`

```
{"$id":"1","$type":"System.Web.Http.HttpError,System.Web.Http",
"Message":"Anerrorhasoccurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"The'ObjectContent`1'typefailedtoserializetheresponsebodyforcontenttype'application/json;charset=utf-8'.",
"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,
"ExceptionMessage":"Thedatareaderisincompatiblewiththespecified'NotosDB.Data.Customer'.Amemberofthetype,'CustomerID',doesnothaveacorrespondingcolumninthedatareaderwiththesamename.","
....
```

**Edit:** I am using Code First development.

I understood that it has to do with the JSON serialization/deserialization, but what exactly is the problem?

Comment: If you are using EF CodeFirst then why are you using Stored Procedures?

Comment: Because the stored procedures are already wrote in the database. Using them would save the need to retrieve data that afterwards has to be marked as deleted. The complexity of the stored procedures would take a lot of resources to be translated to LINQ queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Breeze.js expects the result to be an entity of the `Customer` type I abandoned the use of the manager and EntityQuery in favor of the AJAX implementation of breeze.

Now it looks like this:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("deletecustomer")]
    public object DeleteCustomer(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var data = request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result;
        var customerName = data["customerName"];
        string query = "sp_delete_customer @CustomerName";
        SqlParameter CustomerName = new SqlParameter("@CustomerName", customerName);
        var result = _dataContext.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(query, CustomerName);
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Caller function:

```
    var ajaxImpl = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance("ajax");
    var deleteCustomer = function (callback, custName) {
        function querySucceeded(data) {
            log('Customer ' + custName + ' deleted in '+ data +' ms!',
                data, true);
            callback();
            return true;
        }
        return ajaxImpl.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/breeze/DeleteCustomer",
            data: { customerName: custName },
            success: querySucceeded,
            error: queryFailed
        });
    };
```

Now I'm able to call the stored procedure and return the result.